# How to get ASCII art text to be displayed when I opened my .bat file?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I wanted this ASCII art text to be displayed when I opened my .bat file, but the only thing that happens is that when I open the .bat file it closes instantly and I know that it is a problem with how I am putting the ASCII art.

```
@echo off

echo  _______  ______    _______  _______  _______        __   __  ____  
echo |       ||    _ |  |       ||       ||       |      |  | |  ||    | 
echo |    ___||   | ||  |   _   ||  _____||_     _|      |  |_|  | |   | 
echo |   |___ |   |_||_ |  | |  || |_____   |   |        |       | |   | 
echo |    ___||    __  ||  |_|  ||_____  |  |   |        |       | |   | 
echo |   |    |   |  | ||       | _____| |  |   |         |     |  |   | 
echo |___|    |___|  |_||_______||_______|  |___|          |___|   |___| 

pause
exit
```

[image]

Comment: Try putting quotes around the `echo` lines. Like, for example, the first line would be: `echo " _______  ______    _______  _______  _______        __   __  ____ "`.

Comment: It works, but you can see the quotes for some reason and they don't look good aesthetically.

CODE: https://imgur.com/a/cHC7vd1

.bat: https://imgur.com/a/NpIBpvA

Comment: Well, if it’s within the code all you need to do is leave those lines as comments. So your lines would be `:: _______  ______    _______  _______  _______        __   __  ____ `. No need for `echo` or quotes.

Comment: If I do that, when I open it in .bat / cmd it closes automatically/instantly

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do or expect the BAT file to do. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, but since you are here, do you know how to change the color of various texts? For example, having red text and light blue text? because when in my code I put color B and somewhere else I put color A it changes to the color I put below and it doesn't put the texts in the 2 colors that I want

Comment: “…but since you are here…” I am here to attempt to answer the one question you have. Not every single question you have. Bye!

Comment: @Ron .... Actually, you need to put a caret in front of the pipes `^|`. So for example `echo ^|       ^|^|    _ ^|  ^|       ^|^|       ^|^|       ^|      ^|  ^| ^|  ^|^|    ^|` should work but if you remove the caret, you get the error. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```bash
@echo off

findstr /e "_ |" "%~0" & timeout -1 & exit
 _______  ______    _______  _______  _______        __   __  ____
|       ||    _ |  |       ||       ||       |      |  | |  ||    |
|    ___||   | ||  |   _   ||  _____||_     _|      |  |_|  | |   |
|   |___ |   |_||_ |  | |  || |_____   |   |        |       | |   |
|    ___||    __  ||  |_|  ||_____  |  |   |        |       | |   |
|   |    |   |  | ||       | _____| |  |   |         |     |  |   |
|___|    |___|  |_||_______||_______|  |___|          |___|   |___|
```

---

You can also remove the `echo`, and add the lines after the `exit` command, and make sure to end them with `|` and `_` (without additional spaces at the end of the line), then filter the lines of interest and without the use of escapes `^` being necessary

[image]